# how to share docker image in different accounts on mac

Tags: macos, docker

I use my macbook pro to work and study , when I create a docker image in my work account , i cannot use this image in my study account , that's mean to I have to build another same one , that's a lot of disk waste ,is there any way to share docker images in different users on mac ?

Answer (score 0):

The images are stored by user. The location can be changed. If you are using Docker for Mac just change the folder in Docker Preferences.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I’ll try tomorrow cause today I’m busy

Comment: no, this method is to change the data location, but not include account permission.

Comment: And what about beforehand creating a folder with both accounts having permissions, then selecting the folder as disk image location?